# Delphi prevent TRect moving when scrolling

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a `Listview` where I have added a `TRect` with a `TEdit` box and connected it to one cell. Everything works fine but when I resize the window so the scroll bar is visible and change scroll value the Edit box is not locked to the cell. The TRect(TEdit box)  is moving with the scroll values and leave the field where I want it to stay.

Any Suggestions?

Here is the `OnMouseDown` event.

```
var
  pt: TPoint;
  ListItem: TListItem;
  lvHitInfo: TLVHitTestInfo;
  Ind: Integer;
  LVRect: TRect;
  ScrollOffsetHoriz: Integer;
  DeleteObject: TDeleteObject;
begin
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(False), 0);
  try
    pt := ListView.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);

    ScrollOffsetHoriz := ListView.Items[0].DisplayRect(drBounds).Left;
    ListItem := ListView.GetItemAt(pt.X, pt.Y);
    FDeleteRow := -1;
    // over a sub item?
    if Assigned(ListItem) then
    begin
      FillChar(lvHitInfo, SizeOf(lvHitInfo), 0);
      lvHitInfo.pt := pt;
      if ListView.Perform(LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST, 0, LParam(@lvHitInfo)) <> -1 then
      begin
        LVRect.Left := ScrollOffsetHoriz;
        for Ind := 0 to lvHitInfo.iSubItem - 1 do
          LVRect.Left := LVRect.Left + ListView.Columns[Ind].Width;
        LVRect.Right := LVRect.Left + ListView.Columns[lvHitInfo.iSubItem].Width;
        LVRect.Top := ListItem.DisplayRect(drBounds).Top;
        LVRect.Bottom := ListItem.DisplayRect(drBounds).Bottom;

        FSelectedSubIndex := lvHitInfo.iSubItem;
        FSelectedIndex := lvHitInfo.iItem;
      end;
```

Comment: You'll need to explain more. How did you create the edit control? How did you put it inside a list view? Why are you using `WM_SETREDRAW`? What is this code meant to do? Why does it appear in a mouse down event. Please supply an SSCCE.

Comment: Very seldom do you use Window messages in Delphi code. It can be done, but it is the long way round. Using the native options in Delphi is much easier.